# Serializing XML with multiple possible inner elements

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm having trouble figuring out how to construct and configure a class structure for serializing/deserializing XML such as this in .Net:

```
<OuterElem>
    <InnerElem>
        <C1>...</C1>
    </InnerElem>
</OuterElem>
```

Some notes:

- C1 is a complex type.
- There can also be C2, C3 etc. distinct complex types.
- There can be one or multiple of the Cx elements present at the same time.
- OuterElem and InnerElem comes from a different namespace than the Cx elements.
- At runtime (actually compiletime), the complete set of possible Cx elements is well known the current use case, however the wrapping elements are part of a generic solution so preferably they should not depend on or know about the Cx elements.

This is what I have so far:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "urn:outer-ns")]
public class OuterElem
{
    public object[] InnerElem { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "C1", Namespace = "urn:ns1")]
public class C1 { }

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "C2", Namespace = "urn:ns1")]
public class C2 { }
```

But this doesn't give what I want. Serializing with:

```
var xs = new XmlSerializer (typeof(OuterElem),
                            new [] {typeof(C1), typeof(C2)});
var s = new StringWriter();
xs.Serialize (s, outerElemInstance);
```

yields XML as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<OuterElem>
    <Body>
        <anyType xmlns:q1="urn:ns1" xsi:type="q1:C1">
```

How can I make it use the element name C1 instead of this `anyType`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this use case, typically the *InnerElem* has to be decorated with the *XmlElement* attribute as below:

```
public class OuterElem
{
    [XmlElement(typeof(C1))]
    [XmlElement(typeof(C2))]
    public object[] InnerElem { get; set; }
}
```

However as you have mentioned that you are working on a generic solution which shall not depend on the C1/C2... types, one possible solution is to add these attributes through [XmlAttributeOverrides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.aspx)

```
XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
XmlAttributes attribs = new XmlAttributes();
attribs.XmlIgnore = false;
attribs.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute(typeof(C1)));
attribs.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute(typeof(C2)));
overrides.Add(typeof(OuterElem), "InnerElem", attribs);

var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OuterElem), overrides, new [] {typeof(C1), typeof(C2)}, null, null);
var s = new StringWriter();
xs.Serialize(s, outerElemInstance);
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do what I want. Helped me finally get what the the XmlAttributeOverrides class is about.